Coefficient matrix in terms of covariance
I'm currently reading a paper (White et al 2001) on the regression calibration method for addressing measurement error in studies, but am getting stuck on the set up in section 3.1
We have that $A$ and $B$ are vectors of $a$ and $b$ random variables, respectively. $\beta_{AB}$ denotes the $a \times b$ matrix of linear regression coefficients of $A$ on $B$, and $\Sigma_{AB}$ is the covariance matrix.
The paper states that intercept terms are included in all models but their expected values are ignored, so $\beta_{AB} =\Sigma_{AB}\Sigma_{BB}^{-1}$. I don't follow how this result is obtained.
Using the usual formula for regression coefficients, I get the expression $\beta_{AB} = AB^T(BB^T)^{-1}$ but I dont then know how this relates to the covariance matrices (and how / why we ignore the expected values of the intercepts).
EDIT: This is different to the question marked as similar as the emphasis here is on:

Algebraically how to get from $\beta_{AB} = AB^T(BB^T)^{-1}$ to the expression in terms of covariances
What the relevance or necessity is of including the intercepts in the models but ignoring their expectations, and why we can justify doing this


Re the edit: my answer in the duplicate explicitly shows (1) and explains why the intercepts cannot be estimated from covariances alone.
